# I'm using Git - how do people handle working on the same code but on different computers (eg. Work, then Home)?

Tags: git

so i'm using Git as my source control repo. At work, I do some coding during lunch (work computer) or on the train to/from work (crappy laptop). When I get home, I want to continue that work (home pc).

How do people do this with Git? Commit each time?

Here's my workflow...

(At work, on work pc)...

1. Clone Repo.
2. Create / Switch to new Branch
3. Tap Tap Fap Fap Pew Pew Code.
4. Now it's time to go home .... ??????? Commit?

So, are people just committing code .. despite it being incomplete, doesn't compile, etc. etc? and At home / the other computer, doing a PULL and continuing?

Or is there another way to move around your current uncommitted branch code and importing that on the destination-computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is there another way to move around your current uncommitted branch code and importing that on the destination-computer?

Make sure you're working a branch separate from `master`, push that, pull when home, work work work. When changes work and must be merged into `master`, be sure to rebase the branch to hide the fact that some commits didn't actually compile (not just to protect your reputation, but also because reverting to those commits will be senseless).

Comment: can you please elaborate on this rebasing thing, please? Also, can you comment on BUNDLES please and why/why not use that?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: rebasing is a way of changing the history of a Git-controlled project; see the [Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html) for details. I'd never heard of bundling; it seems to be a way of transferring commits without network connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

> So, are people just committing code .. despite it being incomplete, doesn't compile, etc. etc?

Yes, but not into the production branch.  Remember, you're using git which makes it easy to create, merge and delete branches for every tiny thing you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I think what they do is :

1. Clone Repo
2. Create / Switch to new Branch
3. Tap Tap Fap Fap Pew Pew Code.
4. Commit
5. 3 and 4 * n times
6. See that it is time to go home
7. push the development branch to a development branch in the home repo
8. Go home
9. Continue working on the home dev branch.

Answer (score 1):

> So, are people just committing code .. despite it being incomplete, doesn't compile, etc. etc?

Absolutely. Git affords you great flexibility to create and manage local [branches](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-branch.html) for syncing development efforts between different systems.

> and At home / the other computer, doing a PULL and continuing?

Assuming you have a network connection that doesn't block you from doing so, you could [`push`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-push.html)/[`pull`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-pull.html) between systems; SSH is probably the easiest way.

> Or is there another way to move around your current uncommitted branch code and importing that on the destination-computer?

If you don't have a network connection that you can `push`/`pull` between systems, you can use [`bundle`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-bundle.html) to create an archive that you can put on a flash drive to get changes to your home computer. The documentation provides some good examples to get you started.

Answer (score -2):

> Or is there another way to **move around your current uncommitted branch** code and importing that on the destination-computer?

**Disclaimer:** Although this is not a very git-ish workflow, the following proposal will allow one developer to work on different computers without compelling him to commit/push/pull each time he switches from one computer to another.

- Create a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account
- Install it at Work and at Home
- Store your project within the local MyDropbox folder
- Code at Work
- Leave for Home
- Code at Home
- Push whenever you're ready from either work or home

Dropbox will make sure your MyDropbox content (thus your project, along with your .git folder inside) keeps on being synchronized between your registered computers.

**Note:** Git is a file based system. This means that each time one create/update a source code file, stage a file, create a branch, tag a commit (or a tree/blob), files are being created/updated on the hard drive. As the main task of Dropbox is live-synchronizing files between computers, the combination works pretty well.